# How to add new JSON column in Postgres

Tags: spring, postgresql, ddl, alter

I am trying to add a json type column to the table, but it doesn’t work and I cannot get normal examples, what am I doing wrong?

```
ALTER TABLE user ADD COLUMN purshased_product SET DATA TYPE JSONB USING purshased_product::JSONB;
```

I'm not trying to change the column, but just create a new one with json type

```
@Convert(converter = PurshasedProductConverter.class)
private PurshasedProductConverter[] purshasedProducts;
```

my variable

Comment: I have a user table, but there is no column with json type

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To add a new column use:

```
ALTER TABLE "user" ADD COLUMN purshased_product jsonb;
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/SVST52826

The `set data type` and `using` clauses are only used to modify existing columns.

---

Note that `user`is a reserved keyword. It's a bad idea to create a table with that name. If you insist on that, you **have** to use double quotes each time you refer to the table (as I did)

Comment: Can not set [Lru.valyaeva.marathon.utils.PurshasedProductConverter; field ru.valyaeva.marathon.model.User.purshasedProducts to ru.valyaeva.marathon.model.PurshasedProduct

Comment: @СамирШахмурадлы: that is not a Postgres error message and most probably does not occur when you run the `ALTER TABLE` statement but somewhere in your application.

Answer (score 4):

**Sample:**

```
ALTER TABLE schema.t_my_table
ADD COLUMN purshased_product jsonb; (You may also use the type json)
```

Please check [here](https://www.compose.com/articles/faster-operations-with-the-jsonb-data-type-in-postgresql/) to understand the diff. between the two data types json and jsonb.

> The data types json and jsonb, as defined by the PostgreSQL
>   documentation,are almost identical; the key difference is that json
>   data is stored as an exact copy of the JSON input text, whereas jsonb
>   stores data in a decomposed binary form; that is, not as an
>   ASCII/UTF-8 string, but as binary code.

Comment: Consider describing the difference on SO.